# Print screen short-cut not working (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: shortcut-keys, print-screen

The print-screen short-cut is set to be the Print-screen button, but when I press on it, it does not work. Any clues?

Any help will greatly be appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: It has also been reported in bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1295994

Answer (score 3):

Try this shortcut key:
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :  Enable Unity Plugin in Compiz Setting Manager to use Print-Screen key.

Answer (score 0):

Install compizconfig-settings-manager:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open (start up) the compizconfig-settings-manager:

```
ccsm
```

Select "Gnome Compatibility" and go to the "Commands" tab.

Under the first option, "Screenshot command line", it should say "Print".

Click on the pencil next to "Print" to edit this to something else.

Comment: Hi. I did that with no result. It is weird that it used to work, and suddenly, it does not work anymore. Yes, I restarted.

Comment: @tomasorti if you are using 14.04+, you nolonger use the gnome-compatibility plugin with unity. If you want to change keybindings, you can set keybindings in ccsm, I believe it's under general options and you must include the command line for the option.

Answer (score 0):

i would like to modify the above command to install CpmpizConfig Settings Manger.
The above mentioned command by @mchid is not working and won't be: 
to install CompizConfig Settings Manger use:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

This commands worsk, I've tested this one personally. 
And if in case, it dose't work, 
use:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

after installing, go to dashboard and search for "CCSM" or enter `ccsm` in the terminal.